# What is the best way to install apache, PHP, MySQL, FTP (virtual hosting), and phpMyAdmin on a production CentOS server?

Tags: linux, lamp

I am working on a small, self-hosted project and I need to have LAMP, FTP, and phpMyAdmin installed.  It needs to be set up so it is safe to have running live on the web.

Is it best to yum install ****** everything, or is there a better way to have everything integrated?

Thanks

Comment: I'd favour yum for the core components (apache, mysql, php, ftp), but do phpMyAdmin manually (the version on most repositories are outdated, and you will want to keep that one up to date - definitely limit access to phpMyAdmin - a different port, an additional password (e.g. htpasswd), etc. as it isn't known for its security). (You could try something like XAMPP for the integrated solution, but I would not recommend it for a production setup). You may consider following some of the 'Perfect Server' guides on howtoforge.com as they provide a good starting point for a secure LAMP install.

Comment: @cyberx86 thanks a bunch.  The "Perfect Server" guides are great resources!

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend not having a public facing PHPmyadmin installation. They frequently find critical or not so critical security flaws in this software and it is a pain to keep updated.

What I usually do in this case is enable PHPmyadmin only from a specific IP or from a VPN IP range. Definitely not from the whole Internet.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use yum and add custom repository for phpMyAdmin which always contains up to date versions. Yum on CentOS can help keep everything up to date.